# How to kill a child thread on keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, multithreading, cherrypy

The cherrypy server is started like this:

```
root = Root()
cherrypy.engine.loggingPlugin = LoggerPlugin(cherrypy.engine)
cherrypy.engine.loggingPlugin.init(root.grapher.writequeue)
cherrypy.engine.loggingPlugin.subscribe()
cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), "/", conf)
```

LoggerPlugin is defined as:

```
class LoggerPlugin(plugins.SimplePlugin):
"""Intended to catch the stop signal and terminate WriteLog"""
def init(self, queue):
    self.logger = WriteLog("viewerlog.log", queue, 2)

def start(self):
    self.logger.start()

def stop(self):
    print "Exit"
    self.logger.stop()
    print "Exited"
```

Finally, WriteLog is:

```
class WriteLog (threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, filename, queue, freq):
    self.out = open(filename, "a+")
    self.queue = queue
    self.freq = freq # The time to sleep after every empty queue, in seconds
    self.exit = False
    super(WriteLog, self).__init__()

def stop(self):
    self.exit = True

def run(self):
    while True:
        if self.exit:
            sys.exit(0)

        """ do stuff """
```

When I press Ctrl+C, the console looks like:

```
 ENGINE Bus STOPPING
 ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer shut down
 ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
 ENGINE Bus STOPPED
 ENGINE Bus EXITING
 ENGINE Bus EXITED
 ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
 ENGINE Waiting for thread Thread-1.
```

Nothing happens after that.

Because the WriteLog is the only thread spawned, it should be the culprit. Even though sys.exit() should be called when WriteLog.exit is set to be True, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Can you show the code for grapher?

Answer (score 0):

hmm,  what version of python and cherrypy are you using?  I ran this code and the thread terminates correctly.

```
import cherrypy 
import sys
import threading            

class Root(object):
    def asdf(self):
        return 'hi'

    def grapher(self):
        return 'hi'

class LoggerPlugin(cherrypy.process.plugins.SimplePlugin):
    """Intended to catch the stop signal and terminate WriteLog"""
    def init(self, queue):
        self.logger = WriteLog("viewerlog.log", queue, 2)

    def start(self):
        self.logger.start()

    def stop(self):
        print("Exit")
        self.logger.stop()
        print("Exited")

class WriteLog (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, filename, queue, freq):
        self.out = open(filename, "a+")
        self.queue = queue
        self.freq = freq # The time to sleep after every empty queue, in seconds
        self.exit = False
        super(WriteLog, self).__init__()

    def stop(self):
        print("WriteLog Exited")
        self.exit = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.exit:
                sys.exit(0)

            """ do stuff """

root = Root()
cherrypy.engine.loggingPlugin = LoggerPlugin(cherrypy.engine)
cherrypy.engine.loggingPlugin.init(root.grapher)
cherrypy.engine.loggingPlugin.subscribe()
cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), "/")
```

Here's my output...

```
[user@dev Scratch_Pad]$ /opt/python3/bin/python3.3 webapp.py
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:26] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:26] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:26] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:26] ENGINE Bus STARTING
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[10/Apr/2014:08:28:26] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:26] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:27] ENGINE Serving on 127.0.0.1:8080
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:27] ENGINE Bus STARTED
^C[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Keyboard Interrupt: shutting down bus
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) shut down
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
Exit
WriteLog Exited
Exited
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Bus EXITED
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
[10/Apr/2014:08:28:29] ENGINE Waiting for thread Thread-1.
```

Here's the process that goes away...

```
500       5526  5452 99 08:23 pts/1    00:00:42 /opt/python3/bin/python3.3 webapp.py
```

I believe the thread doesn't confirm it's going away.  Are you still seeing the process run?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using the CherryPy on Ubuntu's package server, and Python 2.7. It still looks like the thread didn't turn off--at the very end it says "Waiting for thread Thread-1". The problem with that is it prevents the ENGINE from restarting or ending gracefully.

Comment: Even if I make a py change and save it my server stops and restarts correctly... "[10/Apr/2014:10:39:30] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
[10/Apr/2014:10:39:30] ENGINE Re-spawning /home/programmer/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Scratch_Pad/webapp.py".  So the threat is definitely going away for me.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a Python 2.7 bug? :S Other than the print() function difference, my code is identical to your code, but my program hangs after Thread-1 waiting.

Comment: I tested it on winxp with python 2.7 and cherrypy 3.2.4 and it's still working correctly.  Try that code on another system.

Comment: Tested again with python 2.7.5 and cherrypy 3.2.4 on CentOS 6.5 and it's stopping and restarting correctly.

Comment: Would 2.7.3 and 2.7.5 have any significant difference? I guess not, but... At this point it just looks like it's a phantom problem that only occurs on a specific set of equipment :P

Comment: @Sky Did you figure out what was causing it? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Kasisnu No, I'm just assuming it's an act of God and used a workaround. :(